# Sade - I Never Thought I'd See the Day

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> Sade - I Never Thought I'd See the Day
>
> I never thought would be there

are both future in the past?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both sentences talk about the future in the past.

P.S. In the second sentence, I think you left out a word. "I never thought I would be there." sounds better.